# C++: Best way to copy a section of WCHAR[] into a wstringstream?

Tags: c++, string

I have a `WCHAR[]`, a `wstringstream`, and an arbitrary section of the `WCHAR[]` that I want to copy into the `wstringstream`. What is the best way to do this?

It seems that there must be a better way than this:

```
for (int i = start;  i < start + length; i++)
{
     wszStringStream << wchr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Try this:

```
wszStringStream.write(wchr+start, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::copy(wchr, wchr + length, std::istream_iterator<WCHAR>(wszStringStream))
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Shouldn't that start at wchr+start?